# SCSS Compilation error using mixin / semantic grid

Tags: sass, mixins, semantic-ui

I've just added the semantic grid css file to my project and imported it into my homepage.scss. The '.column(x)' is causing a compilation error. I'm obviously doing something stupid - anyone spot the issue?

```
@import '../layout/main.scss';
@import '../base/grid.scss';
$columns: 12;
$column-width: 60;
$gutter-width: 30em;
$total-width: 100%;

.banner{
    .column(6);
     background: pink;
     height: 5em;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

SCSS syntax is different from LESS. You need:

`@include column(6);`

Comment: Excellent thank you, i knew it was something stupid I was missing.